# How do I guarantee two delayed_job jobs aren't run concurrently while still allowing concurrency for other jobs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, concurrency, delayed-job

I have a scenario where I have long-running jobs that I need to move to a background process.  Delayed job with a single worker would be very simple to implement, but would run very, very slowly as jobs mount up.  Much of the work is slow because the thread has to sleep to wait on various remote API calls, so running multiple workers concurrently is a very obvious choice.

Unfortunately, some of these jobs are dependent on each other.  I can't run two jobs belonging to the same identifier simultaneously.   Order doesn't matter, only that exactly ***one*** worker can be working on a given ID's work.

My first thought was named queues, and name the queue for the identifiers, but the identifiers are dynamic data.  We could be running ID 1 today, 5 tomorrow, 365849 and 645609 the next, so on and so forth.  That's too many named queues.  Not only would giving each one a single worker probably exceed available system resources (as well as being incredibly wasteful since most of them won't be active at any given time), but since workers aren't configured from inside the code but rather as environment variables, I'd wind up with some insane config files.  And creating a sane pool of N generic workers could wind up with all N workers running on the same queue if that's the only queue with work to do.

So what I need is a way to prevent two jobs sharing a given ID from running at the same time, while allowing any number of jobs *not* sharing IDs to run concurrently.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution to this? I have a similar problem

Comment: @cash22 I wound up writing a 'command' queue and a 'process' queue.  The command queue loads up the processing queue, which focuses on processing actions.  So you actually wind up with three pools:  a 'queued' pool, which is every job to do, a 'command' pool which consists of special jobs that load from pool one to pool three, and a 'processing' pool that actually does the work.  Give one worker to the command queue, and as many as you like to the processing pool.  The first pool, 'obviously', has no workers.  I don't like it, but it's the best I've come up with to date.

Comment: Thanks @RonLugge. I've decided to prevent this scenario from occurring altogether